# No sound through analog speakers

Tags: dual-boot, sound

Running Ubuntu dual-boot, previously with Win8.1, now Win10.

Using Win10, hit "restart" and chose Ubuntu from grub (altered by me, Windows default).

Analog sound through my external speakers doesn't work.  DisplayPort sound works OK as do USB headphones.  But not my desktop speakers.  Try to fix with alsamixer to no avail, not muted, no volume issue.  End up using the DisplayPort sound until I accidentally freeze the OS (unrelated) and have to hard reset (physical button) the machine.

Boot into Ubuntu and sound works perfectly after that!

Restart from Win10 without power cycling and analog sound in Ubuntu doesn't work.  Hard reset and it does.  Didn't happen with Win8.1

Win10 has no audio issues of its own.  Not sure if cause is Win upgrade but the timing matches up.

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Realtek ALC1150
```

How do I fix it such that sound works without needing a hard reset?